# How to use an IncrementalScoreCalculator in Optaplanner using Java-based configuration?

Tags: optaplanner

I use Optaplanner as an optimisation library. In my code, I use a `ConstraintMatchAwareIncrementalScoreCalculator` to calculate scores. I am trying to move away from XML configuration but I noticed that in the `SolverConfig` class only offers `withEasyScoreCalculatorClass(Class<? extends EasyScoreCalculator>)` as far as score calculators go. Is this intended? How do I set it up to use a `IncrementalScoreCalculator`?

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer:

```
new SolverConfig<>()
            .withScoreDirectorFactory(new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig()
                    .withIncrementalScoreCalculatorClass(MyScoreCalculator.class)
            )
```